# How can I add an animation during image on onclick event? Here is my code

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const images = ["https://images.theconversation.com/files/304244/original/file-20191128-178107-9wucox.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=496&fit=clip", "https://bigcats.be/images/resized/750x-header-cat.jpg", "https://cdn.the-scientist.com/assets/articleNo/66820/aImg/34883/bird-article-s.png", "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-600w-407021107.jpg", "https://cdn.the-scientist.com/assets/articleNo/66820/aImg/34883/bird-article-s.png"];

const left = document.getElementById("carousel-left");
const middle = document.getElementById("carousel-middle");
const right = document.getElementById("carousel-right");

let currentIndex = 0;

function focusImage() {
  const leftSrc = currentIndex - 1 < 0 ? images.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1;
  const middleSrc = currentIndex;
  const rightSrc = currentIndex + 1 >= images.length ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
  left.src = images[leftSrc];
  middle.src = images[middleSrc];
  right.src = images[rightSrc];
}

function previous() {
  currentIndex = currentIndex - 1 < 0 ? images.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1;
  focusImage();
}

function next() {
  currentIndex = currentIndex + 1 >= images.length ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
  focusImage();
}

focusImage();

left.addEventListener("click", previous);
right.addEventListener("click", next);
```

```css
#carousel-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.carousel-side {
  opacity: .5;
  width: 225px;
  height: 140px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#carousel-middle {
  width: 40%;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="carousel-container">
    <img id="carousel-left" class="carousel-side">
    <img id="carousel-middle">
    <img id="carousel-right" class="carousel-side">
  </div>

  <button onclick="previous()">previous</button>
  <button onclick="next()">next</button>
</body>
```

// how to add animation during image changing?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of animation do you want to add?
You are changing the src of the three elements everytime you press a button, a carousel is usually done in a different way: all the imgs (or some of them) are printed in html, then their position is changed dinamically with js and you can use the transition property of css.

Comment: I just want a simple spin or little bouncing effect during changing image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple fade in animation for the image on focus, courtesy of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890153/image-fade-in-and-fade-out-animation-in-javascript-not-jquery/22890210):

```js
  

  const images = ["https://images.theconversation.com/files/304244/original/file-20191128-178107-9wucox.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=496&fit=clip", "https://bigcats.be/images/resized/750x-header-cat.jpg", "https://cdn.the-scientist.com/assets/articleNo/66820/aImg/34883/bird-article-s.png", "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-600w-407021107.jpg", "https://cdn.the-scientist.com/assets/articleNo/66820/aImg/34883/bird-article-s.png"];

    const left = document.getElementById("carousel-left");
    const middle = document.getElementById("carousel-middle");
    const right = document.getElementById("carousel-right");

    let currentIndex = 0;

    function focusImage() {
      const leftSrc = currentIndex - 1 < 0 ? images.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1;
      const middleSrc = currentIndex;
      const rightSrc = currentIndex + 1 >= images.length ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
      left.src = images[leftSrc];
      middle.src = images[middleSrc];
      right.src = images[rightSrc];
     middle.style.opacity=0;
     middle.style.filter='alpha(opacity=0)'; 
     animate(middle,750,0,100);
    }

    function previous() {
      currentIndex = currentIndex - 1 < 0 ? images.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1;
      focusImage();
    }

    function next() {
      currentIndex = currentIndex + 1 >= images.length ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
      focusImage();
    }

    function animate(obj,time,a,b)
    {
        var frame = 30;//FPS Rate, so this is currently set to 30 fps
        var second = 1000;
        var fps = (second/frame);
        var distance = parseInt(b) - parseInt(a);
        var rate = ((distance/frame)*second)/time;
        setTimeout
        (
            function()
            {
                a += rate;
                obj.style.opacity=(a/100);
                obj.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+a+')';
                newTime = time-fps;
                if((parseInt(a) >= parseInt(b) && distance >= 0) || (parseInt(a) <= parseInt(b) && distance < 0))
                {
                    obj.style.opacity=(b/100);
                    obj.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+b+')';
                }
                else
                    animate(obj,newTime,a,b);
            }
            ,fps
        );
    }

    focusImage();

    left.addEventListener("click", previous);
    right.addEventListener("click", next);
```

```css
#carousel-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.carousel-side {
  opacity: .5;
  width: 225px;
  height: 140px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#carousel-middle {
  width: 40%;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="carousel-container">
    <img id="carousel-left" class="carousel-side">
    <img id="carousel-middle">
    <img id="carousel-right" class="carousel-side">
  </div>

  <button onclick="previous()">previous</button>
  <button onclick="next()">next</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I do need a spin effect.